# Convert double to string visual c++

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to convert `double` to `string` in Visual C++

```
hasil = 25;
String ^ myHasil;
this->textTop->Text = myHasil;
```

What should I do to send hasil value to myHasil?

Comment: Wrong language tag. This doesn't look like C++ code.

Comment: You need to use ToString method to accomplish this.

Comment: 25 is an Integer, not a Double.

Comment: Please stop tagging this C++.

Answer (score 2):

This is not C++, this is C++/CLI. You should use the `ToString()` method (available to all types in .NET).

```
this->textTop->Text = hasil.ToString();
```

Comment: `myHasil` is already a string. He seems to want to turn `hasil` into a string, which he claims is a `double`.

Comment: @BoBTFish ya, i want to turn hasil(double) value into myHasil(String). what should i do?

Comment: @BoBTFish, oops, didn't pay attention to the two variable names, thanks for correcting.